# MYSQL trigger error on insert with NEW keyword in CONCAT function

Tags: mysql, triggers, concatenation

I have an issue in mysql trigger insert:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trg1` AFTER INSERT ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN
      SET @column = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_1.col1 SEPARATOR ',')   FROM table2,table3..etc;
      SET @values = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('.','NEW', table_1.col1) SEPARATOR ',') FROM table2,table3..etc);
      INSERT INTO log_table(Description)VALUES(CONCAT(@values));
END;
    $$ 
    DELIMITER ;
```

I am selecting the column names and concatenating it with NEW keyword and then inserting the values in the log table as a single string.

But the values gets stored in string format as **'NEW.col1,NEW.col2**..etc' without the values of NEW keyword.PLs help me out..

[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ1fW.png)

Comment: thanks @subin C Poonamgode..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access  columns in the rows affected by a trigger
> 2. In an INSERT trigger, only `NEW.col_name` can be used.

```
SET @values = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('.',table1.col1,NEW.col1,NEW.col2,NEW.col3) SEPARATOR ',') FROM table2,table3..etc);
```

You used `NEW` inside `''`(quotes).Remove it. and use `NEW.col1`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank u very much @subin ... but when i remove the quotes i get error "Unknown column 'NEW' in 'field list'".. on execution

Comment: Have you used `NEW.col1`.?

Comment: SET @values = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('.',NEW, table_1.col1) SEPARATOR ',') FROM table2,table3..etc);.. here the col1 in table1 has 10 records that forms my column names to concate with NEW keyword

Comment: please find the attached table structure dia @subin

Comment: I cannot add the column names explicitly it will concatented along with NEW keyword from table1.col1..here this column will contain 10 records.I am taking all the 10 records and concatenating it with the NEW.keyword